# USB connectivity software for Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We are searching for USB connectivity software to connect with an Oracle database using Oracle Advanced Security Network Encryption algorithms.

We have a software package that requires a USB connection with handheld mobile devices to upload data from scanned activity.   We are not able to connect via wireless, wireless telephony, or Bluetooth technology.

The software vendor provided a connection package developed by a third party vendor, that works on development databases, but not on production with network encryption activated.  To date, neither the software company nor the third party vendor is able to provide a solution.

My question is:  Does anyone know of software that can provide a USB connection between a mobile handheld device and an Oracle database with Network Encryption activated?

Any help will be deeply appreciated.